# Babel react jsx config not works

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, antd

I'd configured [babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) in **.bablerc**

```
{
  "presets": [...],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": false,
        "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true,
        "useESModules": false
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

But the `jsx` code compiled fail when setting [AntD Table](https://ant.design/components/table/) `locale.emptyText` (the property value can be **React.Node or Function** described in [rc-table](https://github.com/react-component/table))

```
import { Table } in 'antd'
<Table
  locale={{ emptyText=<div><img src="..."></div> }}
>
```

The error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /path/to/page.js: Unexpected token (77:31)

  75 |             dataSource={dataSource}
  76 |             loading={false}
> 77 |             locale={{ emptyText=<div><img src=""></div> }}
     |                                ^
```

Another, I know it works if writing as function:

```
locale={{ emptyText: () => <div><img src=""></div> }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, the locale attribute expects an object and hence key-value pairs separated by `:` and not `=`

```
locale={{ emptyText: <div><img src="..."></div> }}
```

should work

Comment: Oh, I was such a fool....  Besides, does it is not necessary to config `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`? I disabled the plugin and also works.

Comment: I haven't used "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx" for my babel config, I think you might already be using `stage-0` and `react` presets in your config

Comment: I used `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/preset-react` as presets.

Answer (score 0):

```
locale={{ emptyText=<div><img src=""></div> }}
                   ^
```

the error message is clear, you are using `=` instead of `:`